# how to pass a json data into jquery data() or data-caption, data-image, data-any?

Tags: php, jquery, html, json, ajax

this is where my json, ajax goes.

```
 <div id="pic"></div>
```

this is my modal and when i clicked the image through the appended html on #pic.. the modal will show the clicked image...

```
<div class="modal fade" id="image-gallery" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="image-gallery-title"></h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <img id="image-gallery-image" class="img-responsive" src="">
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">

            <div class="col-md-2">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="show-previous-image">Previous</button>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-8 text-justify" id="image-gallery-caption">
                This text will be overwritten by jQuery
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-2">
                <button type="button" id="show-next-image" class="btn btn-default">Next</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my script wherein i want to pass the json data unto jquery data and it seems like the jquery data do not store the passed json data.. i also checked if my json is wrong but it displays the img which i also pass a json data.

```
<script>
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "response2.php",
dataType: "json",
success: function(JSONObject) {
    var peopleHTML = "";
    for (var key in JSONObject) {
        if (JSONObject.hasOwnProperty(key)) {           
            peopleHTML += "<div class='col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb'>";
            peopleHTML += "<a class='thumbnail' href='#' data-image-id=''
            data-toggle='modal' data-title='" + JSONObject[key]["title"] + "' 
            data-caption='" + JSONObject[key]["name"] + "' 
            data-image='./images/gallery/img/" + JSONObject[key]["img"] + "' 
            data-target='#image-gallery'>";
            peopleHTML += "  <img class='img-responsive' 
                src='./images/gallery/img/" + JSONObject[key]["img"] + "' 
                alt='Short alt text'>";
            peopleHTML += "</a>";
            peopleHTML += "</div>";
       }
   }
   $("#pic").html(peopleHTML).hide();
       $("#pic").fadeIn("slow");
   }
});
 </script>
```

this is my php where i pass the json from database to jquery

```
<?php
  $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "ecommerceagri");

 $query = mysqli_query($connection,
   "SELECT a.`Gallery.Photo.SRC` AS img, a.`Gallery.Photo.Title` AS title,
   a.`Gallery.Photo.Caption` AS caption FROM galleryphoto AS a;");

  $someArray = [];

 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
   array_push($someArray, [
      'title'   => $row['title'],
      'caption' => $row['caption'],
      'img' => $row['img']
   ]);
  }

$someJSON = json_encode($someArray);
echo $someJSON;
?>
```

Comment: I don't get the question. Are you trying to pass the JSONObject to where?

Comment: sorry... i am trying to pass json on `"<a class='thumbnail' href='#' data-image-id='' data-toggle='modal' data-title='" + JSONObject[key]["title"] + "' data-caption='" + JSONObject[key]["name"] + "' data-image='./images/gallery/img/" + JSONObject[key]["img"] + "' data-target='#image-gallery'>" ` its on my ajax... but it did not store so i cant view the image, title and caption on modal...

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't get your question as well. Where will the json data come from?

Comment: can we see what's the data you're passing? We might have some ideas on how to make it easier...

Comment: the json data will come from my database using php... in my case.. i will pass 3 datas.. the title of the image, the name of the image, and the caption of the image... its working now... but the only thing i could not make work is the anchor on the ajax...

Comment: this is my php where the json data came from `<?php
include "connection.php";
  $query = mysqli_query($connection,
  "SELECT a.`Gallery.Photo.SRC` AS img, a.`Gallery.Photo.Title` AS title, a.`Gallery.Photo.Caption` AS caption FROM galleryphoto AS a;");
  // Create empty array to hold query results
  $someArray = [];
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    array_push($someArray, [
      'title'   => $row['title'],
      'caption' => $row['caption'],
      'img' => $row['img']
    ]);
  }

  $someJSON = json_encode($someArray);
  echo $someJSON;
?>`